# failed to open stream: Success in opencart ajax request

Tags: php, json, opencart

I have googled for a day without a luck. Can anyone help please??

I have an AJAX request which loads more categories at home page. The code is

```
$json=array();
$template = new Template();
$template->data['categories'] = $this->data['categories'];
$html = $template->fetch($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/category_load.tpl');
$json['success'] = $html;
$json['output'] = $this->render();
$this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
```

While I check the function it gives the correct output. But while trying to load through AJAX it gives the error saying

> failed to open stream: Success in /var/www/html/boomrc/system/engine/controller.php on line 82

Have I done any mistake? I'm new to OpenCart.

Comment: show us the ajax code

Comment: oh ! i m sorry i forgot to add the datatype json.sorry for the bothering

Comment: You have to provide line 82 (and a bit more lines up and down) from controller.php if you want an answer, because that's where your error is coming from. Without that code it is impossible to see what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/category_load.tpl')) {
                    $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/category_load.tpl';
            } 


            $json['content'] = str_replace("\r\n", "", $this->render());
            echo json_encode($jdata);
```

Try this one..

Answer (score 0):

Please use Browser-Debug-Console. 
Be sure, that you doesn't do a cross-domain-request for your ajax.
There are some security-limitations, so you can't do cross-domain request for ajax.

Maybe post your controlle.php (or simplified code of it) here.